# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.Catalogue_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am retrieving my toyName from database and want to session it over to the next page. My session has nothing wrong but I have this error which state as below and i not sure where have i gone wrong. I have 2 link buttons in my .aspx page and this link button that is having error is the second linkButton i created.

Error Message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.Catalogue_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 13:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 14:     {
Line 15:         LinkButton LinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
Line 16:         int toyID = Convert.ToInt32(LinkButton.CommandName);
Line 17:
```

Here is my page_load .cs code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton LinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    int toyID = Convert.ToInt32(LinkButton.CommandName);


    string strConnectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string sql = "SELECT toyID, toyName FROM Toys WHERE toyID=@toyID";


    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionStr);
    myConnect.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnect);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toyID", toyID);


    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text = dr["toyName"].ToString();
    }

    dr.Close();
    myConnect.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's totally wrong.

The `sender` for `Page_Load` is the page, not a `LinkButton`.

Comment: But i am trying to retrieve the toyName everytime the user loads the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a page as a link button.. that's never going to work.
When you are casting the sender in the page load you are technically casting the page

If you want to use session you need to put

```
session["something"]= what ever you are trying to save
```

Then to retrieve it

```
var myVariable = session["something"] (maybe cast this as something)
```

Other than that I am not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I have 2 pages. Firstly, I am trying to retrieve my toyName from the database and store this value as a session variable and pass it over to my second page. I want to use this method as i have many toyNames in my database. My function of these 2 pages is that when user first sees the 1st page, the can select the toys that they want. When they enter the second page, the only the toyName that they select from the first page will be passed to the second page for payment purposes.